# Ajax POST form data is send as GET request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I am creating a chat system. I am sending a form data through ajax method in jquery. My first problem is ajax method is not sending data to proccess.php and page goes to redirect to its self.

```
<div id="chatOutput"></div>
<form id="myform">
    <textarea id="chatInput" name="chatInput"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="send" name="send" value="send" />
</form>
```

and script is :

```
$('#send').click(function () {
    $('#myform').submit();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: function () {
            alert("Submitted!"); // for testing
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

but script is not working and page goes to refresh and i see the variables and its values in the address bar like get method.

if this problem goes to solve, process.php will create a chat.txt and append data from #chatInput into it. and then will append chat.txt 's data to #chatOutput.

After appending data, div#chatOutput 's size goes to change. I want to fixed/specified width and height of this div. After the fixing size, how to scroll to bottom to see the last chatting?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**
You had a syntax error. Make sure u have e.preventDefault(); as the first thing in your event click function. Then the default action will be prevented even when an error occurs later on.

```
$('#send').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //disable default action

    $('#myform').submit();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'process.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: $('#myform').serialize(),
            success: function() {
               alert("Submitted!"); // for testing
            }
        });
    });

    return false; //return something
});
```

Comment: Once the default action is prevented then why submitting form again where as the request is ajax..

Comment: Because the default action is to submit synchroniously and that means reloading the page. You first prevent that to happen and then submit asynchroneously.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do :

```
$('#myform').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'process.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: function() {
           alert("Submitted!"); // for testing
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

You used `$('#myform').submit();` which just submits the form in the normal way and thus ignoring the ajax etc after that.

Also, put this code either after the form itself or within `$(function(){ ... });`

Comment: now page doesn't go to refresh. but ajax method still not working

Comment: So you want AJAX to handle the submit but still refresh the page? You might also need to include the code within `$(function(){ .. });`

Comment: So what was the problem?

Comment: i don't know. i am not getting any alert window. and proccess.php is not creating any text file

Comment: ajax not sending any data to proccess.php

Comment: Well, you said the refresh is working right? Does that work via your script? Because I have a feeling it is not going via your script and because of that is not triggering the AJAX request.

Comment: refresh is not working. refreshing page has solved. i don't want to refreshing page. please see my script in my question. i have written alert function on success of ajax method. i am not getting any alert.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

The simulates the "Submit" button click event

Answer (score 0):

Remove the line:

```
$('#myform').submit();
```

It is submitting the form before your ajax call is made.